Symfony doctrine find entities with In and NotIn criteria does not work. Can not find entities while using array of entities as a parameter
So i've got a problem and I am not sure if i do something wrong or there is some bug.
Working with Symfony 7.2.1
I got two three entities, one of them is a connection.
Ean, Shelf, EanShelfQuantity
So Ean Shelf Quantities got uuid with Ean and Shelf and I am trying to find a Ean Shelf Quantity entities by this:
$eanObjects are array of Ean entity objects,
$shelves are array of Shelves objects,
EanShelfQuantity got columns referenced to ean and shelf.
$criteria = Criteria::create()
                ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->in('ean', $eanObjects))
                ->andwhere(Criteria::expr()->notIn('shelf', $shelves));
            $match = $this->entityManager->getRepository(EanShelfQuantity::class)->matching($criteria);

And I am getting entities of Ean Shelf Quantity that have shelves that are in array parameter in notIn
So i checked and use pure sql query and everything works fine, but when trying to use criteria, or QueryBuilder in EanShelfQuantityRepository it doesn't work

Try to use Citeria with Scalars by ensuring you are passing scalar values (e.g., IDs) instead of entity objects, as Criteria doesn't always resolve objects correctly in database queries.
$eanIds = array_map(fn($ean) => $ean->getId(), $eanObjects);
$shelfIds = array_map(fn($shelf) => $shelf->getId(), $shelves);

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->in('ean', $eanIds))
    ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->notIn('shelf', $shelfIds));

$match = $this->entityManager->getRepository(EanShelfQuantity::class)->matching($criteria);

